# Get UIImage reference

Tags: ios5, uiimage

i'm a bit stuck with UIImage.

In my app directory i have 3 pictures of different flags (red.png, yellow.png, green.png) which represent different severity levels for alerts. I created a class 'Alerte' in which one of the parameters is an UIImage picked from one of these flags. So i give the reference to an image like this:

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"jaune" ofType:@"png"];
UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
```

When i print with an NSLog the image the debug area displays:

```
2012-07-26 11:46:28.546 ApplicationFormulaire[1031:fb03] <UIImage: 0x8144e20>
```

But how can i know which of the 3 flags is pointed out ? if it's the yellow red or green?
Does it exist a way to get back the name of this resource?

I would be grateful if someone can help with dealing with it :D thanks

Comment: You require to pass the selected flag string to respective alert method/class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure but i do not think UIImage keeps information regarding its path.

As an alternative that will allow you to access the correct images would be to store them in a NSDictionary. You could then access each one using [myDict objectForKey:key] to get the red, yellow or green images.

Comment: Thanks Ants, it's really strange that UIImage doesn't keep information, but it's consistent to what i've seen in the apple doc about uiimage properties